# value getControllerInstance is not a member of play.api.GlobalSettings with play 2.4

Tags: playframework

After I upgraded play framework to 2.4,the following error occurs. I have read the documentation that the GlobalSettings is removed in 2.4. But how to rewrite the code below?

Error

```
Global.scala:44: value getControllerInstance is not a member of play.api.GlobalSettings
```

Code

```
override def getControllerInstance[A](controllerClass: Class[A]): A = {
     val instance = controllerClass.getConstructors.find { c =>
     val params = c.getParameterTypes
     params.length == 1 && params(0) == classOf[RuntimeEnvironment[DemoUser]]
}.map {
     _.asInstanceOf[Constructor[A]].newInstance(DemoRuntimeEnvironment)
}
instance.getOrElse(super.getControllerInstance(controllerClass))
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using SecureSocial plugin which is not currently supported with Play 2.4

See [Issue #556](https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/issues/556)